# Predefining pandas aggregations and rename with new version

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregation

In previous versions of pandas, you could do:

```
aggregations = {
    'Col1':{
        'SUM_name': 'sum',
        'MEAN_name': 'mean',
        'MAX_name': 'max',
        'MIN_name': 'min'
    },

    'Other colname':{
        'MEAN_newname': 'mean',
        'MED_newname': 'median',
        'MAX_newname': 'max',
        'MIN_newname': 'min'
    },
}
agg_df = df[df['somecol'] <= 0].groupby(['gbcol']).agg(aggregations)
```

This is deprecated with 0.20. What is the equivalent of this form of aggregation in v 0.20?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is named agg:

```
aggregations = {
    'SUM_name':('Col1','sum'),
    'MEAN_name':('Col1','mean'),
    'MEAN_newname':('Other_colname', 'mean')
}
agg_df = df.groupby(['gbcol']).agg(**aggregations)
```